# VoIP calls dropping

Tags: vlan, pfsense, voip

Currently I have a proxy server running pfSense connected to a 40mb fibre lease line. This lease line has 60 external IP addresses (assigned to each room by a virtual IP in pfSense). On the LAN side of the server, there are 2 managed switches, one for each floor. There are not any VLANs set up currently.

Connected to these switches are several TP-Link routers (one for each room). On each router I have connected up the WAN ports with a static IP address in the range of 192.168.25.0. Each static IP has a bandwidth limiter. Each router has a unmanaged switch on the LAN of the router.

There is currently 1 CAT5e cable going to each room. We cannot increase this number.

This setup runs fine, until tenants use VoIP phones. They get calls dropping when bandwidth usage nears their bandwidth quota.

I am going to be setting up VLAN's on the switch, one for each room. In to each port on the managed switch (VLAN's), I will be putting in a Cisco RV130 router in each room and setting up QoS on these routers. The 2 managed switches will be connected using trunk ports.

My question is - Is this the best setup and will this solve the issue, or is there a better, more reliable way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating queues under your limiters, weighted to give VoIP priority and then rules configured so VoIP goes into the appropriate sub-queue, is your best bet there.